# How to show fragment privew in FrameLayout

Tags: android

I want show a preview of my fragment inside `FrameLayout`.

In fact I want display it only in android studio, And I do not want to render it.

My solution:

In Xml I load `home_fragment` preview using `include` tag:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/nav_view"
    android:layout_below="@id/my_toolbar">

    <include layout="@layout/home_fragment" />
</FrameLayout>
```

In `onCreate` method i remove all child view of FrameLayout:

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_frame);
frameLayout.removeAllViews(); // remove static preview in activity_main.xml
```

Everything works right now.
But I think there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [the tools:showIn attribute](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolsshowin).

So if you have your `main_frame.xml` that `<include>`s your `home_fragment.xml`, in `home_fragment.xml` just point to the container layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    tools:showIn="@layout/main_frame"
    android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Other stuff -->

</FrameLayout>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: No, I don't need it, I want only show a preview in android studio. something like `tools:layout=""` in `include` or `tools:text="test"` in `TextView`